# jquery, problem with ajax call with dataType is json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-1.5

After upgrading to jQuery 1.5.2 I start to have problems with my ajax calls when returning json data.

The error is (returned by templateGet() below):

> Ajax call failed: [object Object]
>   parsererror
>   jQuery152040843801534161517_1302269320612
>   was not called

Heres a sample return json:

```
{"subject":"Test subject","body":"Test body"}
```

And heres the jQuery function

```
function ajax_templateGet(templateid) {
    showLoading();
    var query = '?action=get_template' + '&templateid=' + templateid;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'script/ajax/mail_template/mail_template.ashx' + query,
        data: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#preview_subject").empty().html(data.subject);
            $("#preview_body").empty().html(data.body);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            $.jGrowl($.i18n._('Ajax call failed: ' + xhr + ' ' + status + " " + error), { header: $.i18n._('Ajax call failed!') });
        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            hideLoading();
        }
    });
}
```

Anyone can see what I do wrong?

Comment: Are you using the validation plugin? If so, make sure you get a new copy that's compat with 1.5 - this is a known issue and one that I have had as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just upgraded the jQuery Validation Plugin from 1.7.0 to 1.8.0 and all seems to be working - post your comment as an answer and ill accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the validation plugin? If so, make sure you get a new copy that's compat with 1.5 - this is a known issue and one that I have had as well.

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

Answer (score 0):

You first need to parse the returned JSON value....

You cannot use `data.subject` right away

First you need to download the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) file and add to your app..

then parse the variable `data`

`var response=eval("("+JSON.stringify(data)+")");`

Then use variable `response` instead of `data` in the code you posted

```
success: function(data) {
            var response=eval("("+JSON.stringify(data)+")");
            $("#preview_subject").empty().html(response.subject);
            $("#preview_body").empty().html(response.body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the jquery1.5.2.js find the line:

```
d.ajaxPrefilter("json jsonp", function (b, c, e)
```

and change to

```
d.ajaxPrefilter("jsonp", function (b, c, e)
```

That works, and all of my $.ajax functions are happy again.

---

source :: http://debeerdev.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/jquery-1-5-2-json/